# Pattern for lookup in Go array

Tags: go

Go has convenient syntax to define array lookup tables:

```
var myTable = [...]string{
  'a': "aaaa",
  'b': "bbbb",
  'z': "zoro",
}
```

In some cases (where keys are in known and not too big range) this is more efficient way to make table, than map. However, it is easy to make lookup in map and find if key not in it. But to do lookup by index in this array I have to do:

```
if index < len(myTable) {
  if val := myTable[index]; val != "" {
    // here I know index exists in array and val is its value
  }
}
```

Is there simpler / more common pattern or library function to do this?

Comment: Perhaps wrap  `myTable` in a struct/interface with getters and setters and use a `slice`of  `myTable` to manipulate it. Then your setter method could delete an entry that was empty and you wouldn't have to worry about it. In terms of OOP, that would be an appropriate design. But in that case  `map` would be easier/more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any special builtin syntax to remove the need for a bounds check here.  One option would be to wrap the code in a custom type.  For example:

```
type StringTable []string

func (st StringTable) Get(i int) string {
    if i < 0 || i >= len(st) {
        return ""
    }
    return st[i]
}
```

You can still use the same initialiser syntax with the custom type:

```
myTable := StringTable{
    'a': "aaaa",
    'b': "bbbb",
    'z': "zoro",
}
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", myTable.Get('a'))
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", myTable.Get(-5))
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", myTable.Get('~')) // greater than 'z'
```

You can play around with this example here: http://play.golang.org/p/nhti2dVE8B

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting option. I was thinking because lack of generics I would have to do this for each table type, but idea of making it a custom type is pretty cool because in Go I can define methods on anything. BTW your sample misses the typedef for StringTable

Comment: I must have missed that when copying it into the answer.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

> In some cases (where keys are in known and not too big range) this is more efficient way to make table, than map

Yes. You want to translate your key into an offset in the array. Then you can do the lookup in constant time.

Let's say you know all your keys will be in the set `A-Z`. So you create an array of 26 entries. When a key comes in, you subtract the ASCII value of "A" to get the index into your table. Boom, constant-time lookups, which will be much faster than a map lookup.

Note that you don't actually store the key anywhere, it's implicit. If you want to print out your table, you'd need to generate all keys (`A-Z`) yourself.

Comment: This not answer the question at all though. Thank you I know very well why array lookup is faster than map, and this was stated explicitly in question

Comment: oops, misread the question. Agree with previous answer, there isn't any short-cut, just make a function on the Array.